# Python 3.9 - Jupyter - Pandas - DataFrame : Missing group by column after aggregating

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.9

I have a data frame, I `.groupby()` and `.agg()` after which the data aggregates successfully. However, the label column, in this case, `Year` is no longer a key that can be referenced for plotting the data. That said, the `Year` label is visible when printing the data-frame.

### The code that aggregates:

```
df_grp_by_year = df_grp_by_year.groupby(
    df_grp_by_year['Year']).agg({
        'Avg OHCL': my_stats.get_arithmetic_mean,
        'Low': min,
        'High': max,
        'Med': my_stats.get_median, # statistics.median
        'Var': my_stats.get_variance, # statistics.pvariance
        'Std': my_stats.get_standard_deviation # statistics.pstdev
})
```

### The printed output:

[image]

### The code that fails and associated error:

```
plot.plot(
    df_grp_by_year['Year'],
    df_grp_by_year['Avg OHCL'])
```

> KeyError: 'Year'

What is the work-around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `groupby` and `agg` the column `Year` has become the index of the dataframe instead of a column. Therefore it cannot be called as a column hence the `KeyError`. For the plot you can refer to the `index` or just leave it out because the index will be plotted by default.

```
plot.plot(df_grp_by_year.index, df_grp_by_year['Avg OHCL'])
```

or

```
plot.plot(df_grp_by_year['Avg OHCL'])
```